# define private member variables in single line

Tags: c++

Last class my instructor said that you can't define private member variables in a single line like

```
private:
    int x,y;
```

It doesn't make any sense why he said like that. Could you explain is there any reasonable reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can; You just shouldn't.

The definition of multiple variables on the same line can cause confusion in a few cases (which is probably the reason your instructor told you that).

Ambiguity example (important to know when you learn c++, but also avoided by convention, in most production code bases I've worked in):

```
int* a, b;
```

You would expect here for a and b to be pointers, but instead, the definition above is equivalent to:

```
int *a;
int b;
```

Comment: what are the few cases? would you mind telling them?